# Python - Merge Dataframes / Append on Column

Tags: python, dataframe, join, merge

I have data in the following format:

df1:

| date1 | animal | animal cages sold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/19 10:00:00 | dog | 3 |
| 1/1/19 11:00:00 | horse | 6 |
| 1/5/19 11:00:00 | ferret | 5 |
| 1/12/19 10:00:00 | bird | 2 |
| 1/12/19 11:00:00 | hamster | 3 |

and I want to merge it with the following dataframe: (df2)

| event date | event type | people attended |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/19 | charity | 7 |
| 1/4/19 | food drive | 10 |
| 1/12/19 | raffle | 15 |

with the desired output:

(the dates from df2 can also have 1/1/19 00:00:00 format, it doesn't matter. But the dates from df1 MUST have the time)

| **date** | animal | animal cages sold | event type | people attended |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/19 |  |  | charity | 7 |
| 1/1/19 10:00:00 | dog | 3 |  |  |
| 1/1/19 11:00:00 | horse | 6 |  |  |
| 1/4/19 |  |  | food drive | 10 |
| 1/5/19 11:00:00 | ferret | 5 |  |  |
| 1/12/19 |  |  | raffle | 15 |
| 1/12/19 10:00:00 | bird | 2 |  |  |
| 1/12/19 11:00:00 | hamster | 3 |  |  |

I have tried `output_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='date1', right_on='event date')` but that leads to repeated matches. I only need the rows from df2 to be there once, and be on their own separate row.

I was thinking maybe use `df1.append(df2)` and then somehow make date1 and event date in the same column so I could then sort by that column.

Please please help!!!

Comment: `pd.concat([df1, df2.rename(columns={'event date': 'date1'})])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to concat, not merge.  Just need to rename the date columns first, make the dates actual datetimes for sorting, then concat and sort.

```
df1.rename(columns={'date1':'date'}, inplace=True)
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])

df2.rename(columns={'event date':'date'}, inplace=True)
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])
df = pd.concat([df1,df2])

df = df.sort_values(by='date')
```